# How to properly combine codes with timer?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I need to run this first loop for 6 mins and then run the second loop.

I understand I should be using the milli command and to beware of delay but this is the first Arduino code I’ve ever seen and I can’t understand how it functions or if these delays would mess it up. Typically I would trail and error but I don't have the equipment to verify it's actually working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
1ST PROGRAM
    int buzzerPin = 9;
    void setup() {
      pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    }
    void loop() { 
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(20);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(22);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(24);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(26);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(28);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(30);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(32);
    }


2ND PROGRAM
    int buzzerPin = 9;
    void setup() {
      pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
    }
    void loop() { 
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(20);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(18);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(16);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(14);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(12);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(8);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(3);
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
      delay(6);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a global time variable:

```
int64_t started_time = 0;
```

In setup() get the current time:

```
started_time = millis();
```

In loop() call either func1() or func2() depending on if your time has passed or not:

```
if (millis() - started_time < 360000)
    func1();
else
    func2();
```